# Check Ajax Request is well formed or Not

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I using a ajax request to send a json string to a java web service at the back end from an html form.

**HTML code**..

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Requests form</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var ItemId = null;
  var UserId = null;
  var Token = null;

    submit1 = function() {
    alert("Inside submit function");
    Token = document.getElementById("itemId").value;
    UserId = document.getElementById("userId").value;
    var req = {
            requestoruserId: UserId,
            token: Token,

    }
    send(req);
    };

    send = function(req) {
    alert("Inside send function.");
    alert(JSON.stringify(req));
    $.ajax({
        url: '/flsv2/GetRequestsByUser',
        type:'GET',
        data: JSON.stringify(req),
        contentType:"application/json",
        dataType: "json",

        success: function(response) {
            alert("working");
            document.getElementById("Id").value = response.token;
            document.getElementById("Code").value = response.Title;
            document.getElementById("Message").value = response.Desc;
            document.getElementById("itemId1").value = response.RequestId;
            document.getElementById("userId1").value = response.Owneruserid;
            document.getElementById("date").value = response.Date;

            /*if(parseInt(response.Code) === 27 || parseInt(response.Code) === 28) {
                obj = JSON.parse(response.Message);
                document.getElementById("itemId1").value = obj.itemId;
                document.getElementById("userId1").value = obj.userId;
                document.getElementById("Message").value = obj.date
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("Message").value = response.Message
            }*/
            },

            error: function() {
            alert("not working");
            //alert(data);
             }
            });
            };

           </script>
           </head>
           <body>
           <h1>My Requests FORM</h1>
           <form>
           Request Token Id : <input type="text" name="itemId" id="itemId">  <br/><br/>
           Request User Id : <input type="text" name="userId" id="userId"><br/><br/>
           <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submit1()">
           <h1>OUTPUT</h1>
           token : <input type="text" name="Id" id="Id"><br/><br/>
            title : <input type="text" name="code" id="Code"><br/><br/>
            Description : <input type="text" name="message" id="Message"><br/><br/>
            Request Id : <input type="text" name="itemId1" id="itemId1"><br/><br/>
             Owner Id : <input type="text" name="userId1" id="userId1"><br/><br/>
             Request Date : <input type="text" name="date" id="date"><br/><br/>
             </form>
             <br/>
             <h3><A href="index.html">INDEX</A></h3>
             </body>
             </html>
```

But Every time i click the submit button I get the error alert saying "not working". on the browser console it says the following..

[image: console]

I think the error is because the json request is not well formed. Is there a way of checking whether get() method of json string is well formed or not??

Comment: Check your `Network` tab in Chrome Dev tools, you can see your request headers there.

Comment: You have error in server side script (`/flsv2/GetRequestsByUser`). You have posted client side code. Nothing we can really help...

Comment: 1) check the request status in the console 2) check the logs on your server 3) add the parameters that jQuery gives you to the `error` handler and `console.log` them to see more information. It's true that this may be caused by bad data being sent, but the error is happening on the server, so that's where you need to start the debugging trail.

Answer (score 0):

```
data: JSON.stringify(req)
```

Don't stringify it! jQuery's AJAX API is expecting an actual object here, not a JSON string. It takes the object and constructs the HTTP querystring from it. It cannot do that from the JSON-string-version of your data.

You can see from the error message that the HTTP request is *not* what you want it to be.

This doesn't tell you how to check well-formedness of the AJAX request in general (checking for success is really the only way to do that, as server-side APIs can be anything), but it does tell you how to fix this particular problem:

```
data: req
```

It's a shame the back-end service is giving you an "Internal Server Error": that indicates a bug, because that is not the correct error code for a malformed request.

Comment: Even after deleting all the cached files from chrome I'm still getting the same error in the chrome console..

Comment: @Lucy: It is impossible that you are "still getting the same error" after completely changing the request data format. Read it more carefully because it has changed. And study the documentation for the back-end API you're using to find out what the request should look like.

Comment: @Lucy: I'm not going to debug your entire Java back-end for you... As I said, you need to read its documentation to find out what the request should look like. Compare it to what your request _does_ look like.

Answer (score -1):

I think url you want is '/flsv2/GetRequestsByUser?requestoruserId=whateverId&token=whateverToken'

```js
$.ajax({
        url: '/flsv2/GetRequestsByUser',
        type:'GET',
        //data: JSON.stringify(req),
        params: req, // instead of data...
        contentType:"application/json",
        dataType: "json"
       });
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error.. Any reason behind using param instead of data? All the examples I've seen use data..

Comment: Yeah and I don't see any `params` option in the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

You need to send an object to the "data" parameter of the ajax call. Change the data parameter like the following:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/flsv2/GetRequestsByUser',
        type:'GET',
        //data: JSON.stringify(req),
        data: {"request": JSON.stringify(req)},
        contentType:"application/json",
        dataType: "json"
});
```

This will produce a query string parameter in your url like:

/flsv2/GetRequestsByUser?request=STRINGIFIED_JSON_OBJECT

Comment: Still getting the same error..Any specific reason for sending an object??

Comment: There is no indication that the web API takes a single parameter `"request"` which is a JSON string.